# Formula to detect numbers out of sequence in a single cell

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

At work we currently use a program that outputs product number combinations in a single cell. For example, in cell C2 there will be "1 4 6" to show the customer ordered products 1, 4 and 6. These numbers are separated by a single space. Is there any if() type formula I could use that would detect if the products were out of order like "1 6 4". I do not want to use the text to column conversion as I want to keep it all in one step.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are they always of a specified length?

Comment: No, the products range between 1 and 15 and the combinations could either be of 2 or 3. For example it would be "4 15" and another could be "1 3 12"

Comment: Then I would go with VBA

Comment: A solution does exist using only a pure formula (without VBA or helper cells), but the formula would be an absolute monster because Excel is notoriously bad at parsing, so a ton of really complex manual rules have to be coded in to do seemingly simple tasks. Is this something you are interested in?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offtopic-start

This is weird. About 1 hour ago I was [checking this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767395/how-to-find-coefficients-of-exponential-formula-from-given-pairs-of-numbers), thus I have decided to mimic the input and see what happens. In order to mimic the input, I have built probably what you need:

Offtopic-end

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitSingleColumnToCells()

    Dim rngInput    As Range
    Dim rngOutput   As Range
    Dim myCell      As Range

    'Set manually, it is faster :)
    Set rngInput = Range("A1:A22")

    For Each myCell In rngInput
        'replace multiple space with single space:
        myCell = Replace(myCell, Chr(32), Chr(32))
        Dim inputArray As Variant
        inputArray = Split(myCell)

        Dim col     As Long
        Dim i       As Long
        col = 0
        For i = LBound(inputArray) To UBound(inputArray)
            If Len(inputArray(i)) > 0 Then
                col = col + 1
                myCell.Offset(0, col) = inputArray(i)
            End If
        Next i
        'Probably not needed:
        'myCell.Clear
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Simply check the `rngInput` and adjust it correctly. It would give you the values in the next columns. Plus, it works if the split is with more than one empty space.

Thus, if this is the input:

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate you reaching out. Is there any way this same concept could be converted into a single excel formula that would spit out "Yes" or "No" if added with an If() function. If not I will add in this VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a VBA function which will test if a string of numbers is in ascending order:

```
Function InOrder(nums As String) As Boolean
    Dim numbers As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    numbers = Split(Trim(nums))
    For i = LBound(numbers) To UBound(numbers) - 1
        If Val(numbers(i)) > Val(numbers(i + 1)) Then
            InOrder = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    InOrder = True
End Function
```

This could be used directly in the worksheet. `InOrder("1 4 6")` evaluates to `True` but `InOrder("1 6 4")` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @Vityata Good catch. A `Trim()` makes it more robust. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following is IF based formula built using LOOKUP (same as what imaginaryhuman said)

Source cell containing data like `1 4 6` is assumed to be A2. Not tested heavily.

`=IF(LOOKUP(9E+307,-((MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")))+1))*99,99)+0)-(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" 0 "&A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")))+1))*99,99)+0)))>0,"Out of sequence","In sequence")`